# How to create this multiindex dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to recreate this multiindex dataframe to help me run some tests however I'm struggling. It has 2 levels on each axis. It has to look like this, the values within the dataframe is not important but the structure is.

```
Question            YTA_Q3
Values                   @
Question Values           
YTA_Q3   1       29.014949
         2        5.026059
         3        6.626912
         4        1.356526
         99      41.632222
         96      21.279500
```

index and columns return:

```
df.index
Question  Values
YTA_Q3    1     
          2     
          3     
          4     
          99    
          96  

df.columns
Question  Values
YTA_Q3    @
```

My attempt:

```
l = [['q3','1',99],['q3','2',11],['q3','3',105],['q3','4',97],['q3','99',97],['q3','96',97]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns = ['question','values','@'])
df.set_index(['question'],inplace=True)
df

        values  @
question        
q3      1   99
q3      2   11
q3      3   105
q3      4   97
q3      99  97
q3      96  97
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to construct the expected `DataFrame`.

```
tuples = [('YTA_Q3', 1), ('YTA_Q3', 2), ('YTA_Q3', 3), ('YTA_Q3', 4), ('YTA_Q3', 99), ('YTA_Q3', 96)]
# Index
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Questions', 'Values'])
# Columns
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('YTA_Q3', '@')], names=['Questions', 'Values'])
# Data
data = [29.014949,5.0260590000000001,
  6.6269119999999999,
  1.3565260000000001,
  41.632221999999999,
  21.279499999999999]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=columns)
print(df)

Questions            YTA_Q3
Values                    @
Questions Values           
YTA_Q3    1       29.014949
          2        5.026059
          3        6.626912
          4        1.356526
          99      41.632222
          96      21.279500
```

Comment: Thanks! nesting had me confused as hell!